# What is a filesystem API?

Tags: filesystems, api

I know what an API is (Application Programming Interface) but was wondering if someone could explain what a "filesystem API" is. Thank you

Comment: You know what an API is, but do you know what a "filesystem" is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Application Programming Interface that lets you talk to the file sytem kernel code of your Operating System. This way you can do things like reading and writing files, as well as setting their properties.

Answer (score 3):

An API for enumerating files and directories, as well as creating, reading, writing and deleting files,
reading and modifying file attributes and security descriptors.